# Batch table creation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table called tests, i want to use it to store all tests but one test can have over 350 questions here are the column names i have so far

```
question_1  
answer_1_question_1  
answer_2_question_1  
answer_3_question_1 
answer_4_question_1  
answer_5_question_1

question_2  
answer_1_question_2  
answer_2_question_2  
answer_3_question_2 
answer_4_question_2  
answer_5_question_2
```

I have 25 of these so as of now the application can only store 25 questions and each question can have up to 5 answers and that for the multiple choice question.

the short answers are basically the same see below.

```
Short_answer_question_1  
sa_answer_1_question_1  
sa_answer_2_question_1  
sa_answer_3_question_1 
sa_answer_4_question_1  
sa_answer_5_question_1

Short_answer_question_2  
sa_answer_1_question_2  
sa_answer_2_question_2  
sa_answer_3_question_2 
sa_answer_4_question_2  
sa_answer_5_question_2
```

so the question is how do i write a query to create all these tables and don't have to  do them one by one in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to rethink your database structure?

Comment: You're going about this wrong.  You should really have seperate tables.  One for questions.  One for answers, with an id pointing to the question.  And one for responses that links to both.  Doing it that way, you will have no limitations on how many of each you can have.

Comment: What you have here is literally the same exact thing as a progam I just released myself a couple of weeks ago.  That's how I designed it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn  houl would you write the insert query and get the results with tables like that im not great with mysql.

Comment: There's no simple answer to that.  You need to design your table structure 1st.  Then come back and ask how to do the inserts.  The issue you are having is that you are not taking advantage of the "relational" aspect of the database.  Because you have too much stuff 'horizontally', it makes populating it 'vertically' VERY difficult and space consuming.

Comment: im remaking the tables now like you suggested... just wish there was a query i could use to make all 350 columns :/

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not your tables are designed correctly, it should be straightforward to write simple php programs that emit valid MySQL data-definition language to define these tables.

If this is a one-off thing, you could write the program to write the SQL to a web page, then cut and paste it into a "buiild.sql" source file which you can keep in version control.